# Xubuntu. Help me build a system using Xubuntu with older laptop configured with Win/xp sp3 using only 1 of the partitions both partitions are 9.5 GB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, xubuntu, ubuntu-minimal

I would like to give specs of this machine after explaining my situation.

First, I have no background knowledge of (Unix, Linux, Ubuntu... etc.) What I want from you, instructions of how to download directly to the dell laptop using Mozilla Firefox browser the operating system Xubuntu. I may have to buy a CD from some place if I can't direct download and extract online. Dell Laptop does not recognize a flash drive and CD player is the only option other then direct download.

Second, I would like to know of any web site you know of that has basic tutorial of Xubuntu (Written or Video that's downloadable). Any teaching aid on recognizing what the screen will look like and how to interact with Xubuntu. I would like to do this learning while having a dual system of Windows XP and Xubuntu. This computer laptop is used mainly for watching movies online and listening to music online very little of anything else would be done with this laptop.

So basically I have asked how would you build a system with these requirements in mind.

1. Hard drive space available 9.5GB in 2nd partition
2. Memory 261,500 KB physical.
3. Vendor Dell Latitude D6xx  something. Can't remember at this moment.
4. (No Wireless Card installed).

Comment: Do you want to download Xubuntu, or do you want to download a file using Xubuntu? The phrase " instructions of how to download directly to the dell laptop using Mozilla Firefox browser the operating system Xubuntu" isn't very clear. All it says is that you want us to tell you how to download something onto a computer that is already running Xubuntu and Mozilla Firefox. Can you edit your question and make this a little bit more clear?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) We're sorry but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: It seems, that your machine cannot boot from USB or DVD reader. In that case, you'll need to [install from a “Mimimal CD” edition](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) (includes terse downloading, burning, and installation instructions), which is the same for all flavours of Ubuntu including Xubuntu.

Comment: Before you do anything, I recommend removing Windows XP or upgrading your Windows version. Windows XP is no longer getting security updates and is no longer supported by Microsoft. It will also make it less likely that you'll get help dual-booting in the future. Second, I don't think you'll need a guide on Xubuntu. It is very easy-to-use and self-explanatory. If you want help installing, Xubuntu uses the same installer as regular Ubuntu so you can read a guide on Ubuntu installation at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). Your hardware does not meet the minimal systems requirements for Xubuntu. however you can install Lubuntu 32-bit on your machine, preferably the Long Term Support (LTS) Lubuntu release. Lubuntu is similar to Windows XP in look, feel and hardware requirements.

Answer (score 1):

On a machine with only 256MB or RAM, there is only one choice: [Lubuntu 32 bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso)

Then just:

1. Make a [back-up of your entire disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)
2. follow the [excellent official installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu).

**Optional** Remove Windows XP completely after you're familiar with Lubuntu and give the additional disk space to Lubuntu.